# Applications of the Triangle Inequality Proof

Tags: probability, geometry

I am trying to understand the proof that the forecast error for an ARIMA(p,d,q) model becomes larger when the forecast period grows larger.

Suppose I take the ARIMA(p, q, d) :

$$\nabla^d y_t = \sum_{i=1}^p \phi_i \nabla^d y_{t-i} + \sum_{j=1}^q \theta_j e_{t-j} + e_t$$

$$\nabla^d y_t = \phi_1 \nabla^d y_{t-1} + \dots + \phi_p \nabla^d y_{t-p} + e_t - \theta_1 e_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_q e_{t-q}$$

$$y_t - y_{t-d} = \phi_1 (y_{t-1} - y_{t-d-1}) + \dots + \phi_p (y_{t-p} - y_{t-d-p}) + e_t - \theta_1 e_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_q e_{t-q}$$

$$y_t = c + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \dots + \phi_p y_{t-p} + e_t - \theta_1 e_{t-1} - \dots - \theta_q e_{t-q} + y_{t-d}$$

$$y_t = c + \sum_{i=1}^p \phi_i y_{t-i} + \sum_{j=1}^q \theta_j e_{t-j} + e_t + y_{t-d}$$

where:

- $y_t$: the value of the time series at time t.
- $\nabla^d$: the differencing operator, which takes the difference between the value of the time series at time t and the value at time t-d. The parameter d determines the order of differencing.
- $\phi_1, \dots, \phi_p$: the autoregressive coefficients, which specify the dependence of the current value of the time series on its past values. The parameter p determines the order of the autoregressive model.
- $e_t$: the error term at time t, which represents the deviation of the actual value of the time series from the predicted value based on past values.
- $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_q$: the moving average coefficients, which specify the dependence of the current value of the time series on the past error terms. The parameter q determines the order of the moving average model.
- $y_{t-d}$: the value of the time series at time t-d, which is used when performing differencing with parameter d.
- $c$: a constant term, which represents the mean value of the time series when all other terms are zero. This term is optional and can be omitted from the model. $c = y_d - \phi_1 y_{d-1} - \dots - \phi_p y_{d-p}$ is a constant.

The forecast at time $t+h$, where $h$ is the number of time steps ahead, can be written as:

$$\hat{y}{t+h} = c + \phi_1 y{t+h-1} + \cdots + \phi_p y_{t+h-p} - \theta_1 e_{t+h-1} - \cdots - \theta_q e_{t+h-q}$$

where:

- $y_t$ is the observed value at time $t$
- $c$ is the constant term
- $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_p$ are the autoregressive parameters
- $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_q$ are the moving average parameters
- $e_t$ is the error term at time $t$.

The prediction error at time $t+h$ is then given by:

$$e_{t+h} = y_{t+h} - \hat{y}_{t+h}$$

**Here is where I get confused:**

Suppose we take the absolute value of this error and applying the **triangle inequality** -  we get:

$$|e_{t+h}| = |y_{t+h} - \hat{y}{t+h}| \leq |y{t+h} - y_{t+h-1}| + |y_{t+h-1} - \hat{y}_{t+h-1}|$$

- The first term on the right-hand side is simply the size of the change in the observed values between time $t+h$ and time $t+h-1$.
- The second term is the prediction error at time $t+h-1$.

Substituting in the expression for $\hat{y}_{t+h-1}$ and taking the absolute value, we get:

$$|y_{t+h-1} - \hat{y}{t+h-1}| = |e{t+h-1}| \leq |y_{t+h-1} - y_{t+h-2}| + |y_{t+h-2} - \hat{y}_{t+h-2}|$$

Repeating this process for $h-1$ steps, we get:

$$|e_{t+h}| \leq |y_{t+h} - y_{t+h-1}| + \cdots + |y_{t+1} - y_t| + |e_{t+1}|$$

Now, assuming that the errors are uncorrelated and have constant variance, the expected value of the square of the prediction error at time $t+h$ is given by:

$$\operatorname{E}(|e_{t+h}|^2) = h \sigma^2$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error term. **Thus, as the forecast horizon $h$ increases, the expected value of the prediction error grows linearly with $h$.**

I am not sure that I fully understand how the triangle identity can be used in this proof - can someone please help me understand?